# MDM iPad - Mass update without downloading update X times

Tags: ios, software-update, mobile-device-management

This is a difficult one. I'm going to update around 30 iPads (iOS 8 to 9.2.1) on location with a bad internet connection. Because of the speed and wifi signal I want to download the iOS update only once and install it on all iPads. The problem is, when I connect the devices to my macbook it wants to configure as new or want to use my own last backup.

Does anyone know how to update all iPads without downloading the same iOS update X times?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can't download the update once and install it via Apple Configurator / iTunes. Best way is to setup MDM tool + DEP (Device enrollment Program) in supervised modus and install update over the air.

Answer (score 1):

An OS X/macOS server with the caching service enabled will prevent all the iPads from fetching the same update from Apple's.

Comment: I love this service of Server.app on macOS. Huge benefit for storing updates, app downloads, and in some cases personal iCloud assets.